# A game of locks and keys

Tags: code-golf, graph-theory

There are *n* boxes, numbered *1-n*. Each box is locked, such that it can be opened by only one corresponding type of key (also numbered *1-n*). These keys are randomly scattered in the boxes (one box may have any number of keys, one key may have any number of duplicates), and then all boxes are shut. A treasure (numbered *0*) has also been locked in many of the boxes.

You have hired a locksmith to retrieve all the treasure. He charges for each box he cracks open. There is no charge for opening a box for which the key is already available.

Input is the contents of each box. You can decide the format of the input.

**Output the minimum cost required to get the treasures.**

*Notes*

1. Your algorithm may take a long time, but that is irrelevant.
2. Shortest code wins.
3. No need to bother about invalid input.

**Sample data**

Here line *i* represents the keys present in box *i*.

Input

```
2 0
3
4 0
5 6 0
6
0
```

Output

```
1
```

Input

```
2 0
3 0

4 0
6
5 0
```

Output

```
3
```

Input

```
2 4 0
3 0

1 0
6
5 0
```

Output

```
2
```

Input

```
1
3 4


2 6
5
```

Output

```
0
```

Comment: Is this perhaps related to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eivGlBKlK6M)?

Comment: Also related: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23150/how-to-beat-count-dracula

Comment: @VoteToClose Nice video. It is similar, except that it talks of a mathematical puzzle and specific algorithm, rather than a generalised one.

Comment: @VoteToClose, not really. That question is about permutations; this question is graph reachability plus smallest covering set.

Comment: This seems related to this puzzle about 100 locked boxes of wood and steel: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/17852/4551

Comment: I'm not a fan of the specific input format. I expect I'd need a decent fraction of my code just to put it in a usable form. In the future, I suggest allowing more flexible forms of input for algorithmic style problems.

Comment: @xnor The input is simple only. How can I make it simpler than this?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code It's not about simplicity but about flexibility. Commonly, challenges that require structured input allow any convenient list format, as long as the data is not preprocessed. Depending on the language that could mean a whitespace separated file like you have, or it could mean `[[1] [3 4] [] [] [2 6] [5]]` or maybe `{{1},{3,4},{},{},{2,6},{5}}`. This way, most languages can reduce reading the input to something as trivial as `i=eval(read())` and focus on the fun part of the challenge.

Comment: I am missing something to understand this puzzle. How does the last one work to zero if we don't start with any keys and locksmith charges to open a box we don't already have the key for?

Comment: @qumonio Only all the treasure (0s) need to be found. Since there are no 0s, we have already completed the challenge even before opening any box.

Comment: @xnor  @ MartinButtner Done.

Answer (score 6):

## CJam, <s>59</s> <s>52</s> <s>50</s> <s>49</s> <s>45</s> <s>43</s> 42 bytes

```
qN/ee::~e!{_0+{0a&}#>W%_{1$|(z@-},,\;}%:e<
```

*Thanks to @MartinBüttner for golfing off 3 bytes and paving the way for 4 more!*

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2Fee%3A%3A~e!%7B_0%2B%7B0a%26%7D%23%3EW%25_%7B1%24%7C(z%40-%7D%2C%2C%5C%3B%7D%25%3Ae%3C&input=2%200%0A3%0A4%200%0A5%206%200%0A6%0A0).

#### How it works

```
qN/      e# Read all input and split it at linefeeds.
ee       e# Enumerate the lines.
         e# STACK: [[0 "i0 i1 ..."] [1 "j0 j1 ..."] ...]
::~      e# Apply ~ (bitwise NOT/evaluate) to each item of the pairs.
         e# STACK: [[-1 i0 i1 ...] [-2 j0 j1 ...] ...]
e!       e# Push all unique permutations of the resulting array.
{        e# For each permutation:
  _0+    e#   Push a copy and append 0 to it.
  {0a&}# e#   Find the first index of an element that contains 0.
  >      e#   Discard all previous elements of the array.
  W%     e#   Reverse the resulting array.
         e#   We now have a (partial) permutation that contains
         e#   all treasures and ends with a treasure.
  _      e#   Push a copy. The original (which contains lists, but no 
              numbers) will serve as accumulator.
  {      e#   Filter; for each list in the array:
    1$|  e#     Push a copy of the accumulator and perform set union.
    (    e#     Shift out the first element (bitwise NOT of 0-based index).
    z    e#     Apply absolute value to push the 1-based index.
    @-   e#     Perform set difference with the former state of the 
         e#     accumulator. This pushes an empty list iff the 1-based
         e#     index was already in the accumulator, i.e., iff we already
         e#     had a key.
  },     e#   Keep the element if we did not have the key.
  ,      e#   Count the kept elements.
  \;     e#   Discard the accumulator from the stack.
}%       e#
:e<      e# Get the minimum of all results.
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation for us without the gift of CJam understanding? :D I'd like to know how this works.

Comment: @VoteToClose Look at this [CJAM101](http://usandfriends.github.io/CJam101/)

Comment: `array long &` works, so you can remove the `a` from `0a&`. Sadly this makes it slightly harder to catch you.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Unfortunately, if I replace `0a&` with `0&`, I also have to replace `0+` with `0aa+`, since `0 0&` is falsy.

Comment: @VoteToClose I've edited my answer.

Comment: I don't believe it's producing the right result here http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2Fee%3A%3A~e!%7B_0%2B%7B0a%26%7D%23%3EW%25_%7B1%24%7C(z%40-%7D%2C%2C%5C%3B%7D%25%3Ae%3C&input=2%200%0A3%0A4%200%0A5%206%200%0A6%0A0

Comment: @qumonio Each box in your example contains the key for the next one, so you only have to pay to open the first.

Comment: @Dennis I am sorry, I had some linkage trouble and I meant to provide input similar to this JS array : `[ [4,0], [1,3,4], [0], [6,0], [3,0], [5]]` I think I got it set properly here http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2Fee%3A%3A~e!%7B_0%2B%7B0a%26%7D%23%3EW%25_%7B1%24%7C(z%40-%7D%2C%2C%5C%3B%7D%25%3Ae%3C&input=4%200%0A1%203%204%0A0%0A6%200%0A3%200%0A5

Comment: @qumonio Paying for box 2 gives you keys to 1, 3, and 4. Box 4 contains a key to 6 which, in turn, contains a key to 5.

Comment: brilliant. I think this puzzle is too much for me. congrats on the win :)

Answer (score 2):

### CJam (53 bytes)

```
Nq+N/:a::~:A,_m*_.&{,}$_{{_Af=e_|}:PA,*A,,^0-P0&!}#=,
```

This is rather too slow for the online interpreter.

#### Dissection

```
Nq+N/:a::~:A      e# Parse the input into arrays and store in A
,_m*_.&           e# Generate (with duplicates) a powerset of [0 1 ... n]
{,}$              e# Sort by size
_{                e# Create a copy and search for first index satisfying...
  {_Af=e_|}:P     e#   Store in P a block which does a reachability expansion
  A,*             e#   Apply it n times (no path can be longer than n)
  A,,^0-          e#   Invert to get the unreached nodes (except 0)
  P               e#   Apply P again to see what's reached from the unreached nodes
  0&!             e#   Check that it doesn't include [0]
}#
=,                e# Look up the powerset element at that index and find length
```

Comment: I received `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` with your program.

Comment: @qumonio, it's not particularly scalable. I haven't tested it with inputs larger than the test inputs in the question, so I'm not sure how far it can go on a standard 1GB heap.

Comment: I was trying the 6 line here shown as an array in JS: `[ [4,0], [1,3,4], [0], [6,0], [3,0], [5]]` of course with the input style as shown in the original post.

Comment: @qumonio, on my computer it handles that input fine with only 128MB of heap, which is less than it has by default.

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 173 bytes

`l` is the one you wanna call.

Not sure whether I shouldn't use a pseudo-`Map` instead (`[(Int,[Int])]` instead of `[[Int]]`).

```hs
l=o[].map(map read).map words.lines
o[]b|0`notElem`concat b=0|0<1=1+minimum[o[n]b|n<-[1..length b],b!!(n-1)/=[]]
o(n:k)b=o(filter(/=0)(k++b!!(n-1)))(take(n-1)b++[]:drop n b)
```